# Issue with generating a dictionary function

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

There is a certain function like so…

```
func getCricketerList() {
    presenter?.cricketerListDidFetch(cricketerList: getAllCricketerDetail())
  }
```

Here, `getAllCricketerDetail()` is given as…

```
func getAllCricketerDetail() -> [Cricketer] {
    var cricketerList = [Cricketer]()
    let allCricketerDetail = Common.generateCricketerList()
    for cricketer in allCricketerDetail {
      cricketerList.append(Cricketer(attributes: cricketer))
    }
    return cricketerList
  }
```

The `Common.generateCricketerList()` is given like so…

```
class Common: NSObject {

  class func generateCricketerList() -> [[String: String]] {
    return [["name": "Sachin Tendulkar","country":"India"],["name":"Brett Lee","country":"Australia"],["name":"Wasim Akram","country":"Pakistan"],["name":"Sourav Ganguly","country":"India"],["name":"Jonty Rhodes","country":"South Africa"]]
}
}
```

This is working fine. Now elsewhere I’m trying to implement a similar functionality. For that, I have defined a class called `Common2`. Now, I want in this class 3 key/value pairs namely name,description and image. That I’ve given like so…

```
class Common2: NSObject {
  
  func generateCricketerDetailList() -> [[String:Any]] {
    return [["name": "Sachin Tendulkar","description":"add description here","image": UIImage(named: "Sachin.jpeg")!],["name":"Sourav Ganguly","description":"add description here","image":UIImage(named: "sourav.jpeg")!],["name":"Adam Gilchrist","description":"add description here","image":UIImage(named: "adam.jpeg")!],["name":"Jonty Rhodes","description":"add description here","image":UIImage(named: "adam.jpeg")!],["name":"Wasim Akram","description":"add description here","image":UIImage(named: "wasim.jpeg")!]]
  }
}
```

Now when I try to implement `Common2` in the function I get the suggestion like so…
[image]

Now if I click on the option that is highlighted, I get something like this...

[image]

What am I to do...? What is it that I'm doing wrong here...?

Also is the function `generateCricketerDetailList()` I defined in `Common2` correct...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make it a class function like the other one...

```
class func generateCricketerDetailList() -> [[String:Any]] {
    return [["name": "Sachin Tendulkar","description":"add description here","image": UIImage(named: "Sachin.jpeg")!],["name":"Sourav Ganguly","description":"add description here","image":UIImage(named: "sourav.jpeg")!],["name":"Adam Gilchrist","description":"add description here","image":UIImage(named: "adam.jpeg")!],["name":"Jonty Rhodes","description":"add description here","image":UIImage(named: "adam.jpeg")!],["name":"Wasim Akram","description":"add description here","image":UIImage(named: "wasim.jpeg")!]]
}
```

---

Unrelated to the problem, i recommend you store the information in a struct rather than a dictionary. Unless you are trying to mimic the api response for the sake of this question.

Comment: oh yes!..I had missed that @Rakesha Shastri...:)Thanks...:)

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand the basic OOP notion of classes and instances? `generateCricketerDetailList` is an *instance* method, but you are trying to call it as if it were a *class* method.